# Given a polynomial $p(x)$ and its coefficient vector $c$, find a vector $d$ such that $\mathbf{c}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{d}$ is equal to $\int_0^1 p(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Given is a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ in monomial basis, $p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i = (1,x,x^2,\ldots)\,\mathbf{c}, \, \mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and its coefficient vector $c$.

I'm trying with no luck to find a vector $d$ such that $\mathbf{c}^\mathsf{T}\mathbf{d}$ is equal to $\int_0^1 p(x)$. Can anyone give me a hint how I can approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $\int_0^{1}p(x) dx= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \frac {a_k} {k+1}$ if $p(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} a_kx^{k}$. So $d=(1, \frac 1 2,...,\frac  1{n+1})$ will do.